# Cannot establish JDBC connection

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I am getting below error while running the jmeter command in non-gui mode from jenkins.

> 1525245708238,63941,JDBC Request,null 0,java.sql.SQLException: Cannot
>   create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: The Network Adapter could
>   not establish the connection),SQL 1-1,text,false,,106,0,1,1,0,0,63940
>   1525245772189,63135,JDBC Request,null 0,java.sql.SQLException: Cannot
>   create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: The Network Adapter could
>   not establish the connection),SQL 1-1,text,false,,106,0,1,1,0,0,63135

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the host where Jenkins (or its build agent) lives cannot establish connection to Oracle host so you will need to inspect/amend [Oracle Network Configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/network.htm#ADMQS0411) or your operating system [firewall](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(networking)) settings to allow connections from Jenkins master or build agent.

You can use [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/overview/index.html) or [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) or similar in order to verify connectivity, given you will be able to establish connection to the database from Jenkins host or build agent - JMeter should also be able to connect and execute queries (assuming you have appropriate [Oracle JDBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) in [JMeter Classpath](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732729-How-to-use-Different-JDBC-Drivers))

Comment: i am able to connect to the db using sql developer and from jmeter as well. But when i am running the command in non-gui mode it is giving the aforementioned error. how can i check whether any firewall is causing this issue?